# como usar importmap(rails) en windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy aprendienedo rails, y estoy trabajando en windows 10, instalé importmap y deacuerdo a la documentración ya puedo instalar librerias js de esta manera, sin embargo no funciona

```
bin/importmap pin jquery
```

He tratado así:

```
rails importmap pin jquery
```

Y obtengo este error

```
Don't know how to build task 'importmap' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

Como podria instalar librerías en rails mediante importmap

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ...y el error sería?

Comment: Se me pasó ponerlo, ya lo actualicé Don't know how to build task 'importmap' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)

Comment: Al intentar las 2 opciones para [instalar](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#installation) ¿te arrojó algún mensaje? Y cuando ejecutas `bin/importmap pin jquery ` te arroja el mismo error que con `rails importmap pin jquery`?